# Non-markovian random walks and their applications in machine learning

Tags: stochastic-processes, machine-learning, random-walk

I'm searching applications of random walks in machine learning. In particular, applications of random walks with long memory. An example of this kind of processes is the so called ELEPHANT RANDOM WALK.

The ERW is a model studied in physics and recently has been used to study autism.

I've been searching a lot of time without success. 
I'll appreciate comments, references, papers and books that introduce in this topic.

All this is for my thesis.